# Convert image into hexadecimal format with Python

Tags: python, image, hex

I have a jpg file under the `tmp` folder.

```
upload_path = /tmp/resized-test.jpg
```

I have been using the codes below:

Method 1

```
with open(upload_path, "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

Method 2

```
def imgToHex(file):
    string = ''
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        binValue = f.read(1)
        while len(binValue) != 0:
            hexVal = hex(ord(binValue))
            string += '\\' + hexVal
            binValue = f.read(1)
    string = re.sub('0x', 'x', string) # Replace '0x' with 'x' for your needs
    return string
imgToHex(upload_path)
```

But none of them are working as I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the binascii package for this. It will convert it in to a hex string.

```
import binascii
filename = 'test.png'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
print(binascii.hexlify(content))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @pansul-bhatt but when I try to set it into reponse, I get this error: `"raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")"` My return code is like this: return {
            `'header': {
                'Content-Type': content_type
            },
            'body': encoded_string
        }`

Comment: Actually, I am trying to apply in AWS Lambda. When I try to give the response like above, I get this error.