# Turning image file into text file with Hexademicals

Tags: python, image-processing, rgb

Hello I'm trying to do school project using Python and I'm getting stuck so I would like some help. 
I'm trying to make a import a image and read it and export a text file in hexademicals.

For example with this image I made with MS Paint[image]

Let's pretend this is a 9 pixel image. I would like to import this image and turn it into a text file that reads somethings like

```
FF0000 0000FF 00FF00
0000FF FF0000 00FF00
00FF00 FF0000 0000FF
```

Would this be possible using Python? Or do I need another programming language to do it?
Thanks in advance guys!(Sorry If i have bad English)

Comment: *"Would this be possible using Python?"* - Yes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-can-i-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python

Comment: This post help to convert image to hex format link(https://stackoverflow.com/a/45544814/5855946)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert image into hexadecimal format with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544755/convert-image-into-hexadecimal-format-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really speak Python, but I have tried to learn some and this seems to do what you ask. I may not be very Pythonic, but at least it only uses PIL, which is a lot smaller and easier to install than OpenCV!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import sys
from PIL import Image

# Check image supplied as argument
if len(sys.argv)!=2:
    sys.exit("ERROR: Please specify a file")

# Load image
img=Image.open(sys.argv[1])

# Retrieve dimensions
w,h=img.size

# Make RGB if palettised
if img.mode=="P":
    img=img.convert('RGB')

p=img.load()
for y in range(0,h):
    for x in range(0,w):
        r,g,b=p[x,y]
        str="%02x%02x%02x "%(r,g,b)
        print(str,end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it at the command-line without any need for Python, using **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

It will work for PNG, JPEG and around 200 other image types. Let's make a sample image:

```
convert xc:red  xc:blue xc:lime +append    \
     \( xc:blue xc:red  xc:lime +append \) \
     \( xc:lime xc:red  xc:blue +append \) \
     -append start.png
```

And let's enlarge it so you can see it (I could have done it one go):

```
convert start.png -scale 400x start.png
```

[image]

Now to your question, I can convert that to raw RGB (by interpreting all the image sizes, palettes, compression, and headers) and pass that through `xxd` for hex formatting:

```
convert start.png -depth 8 rgb: | xxd -g3 -c9 -u
00000000: FF0000 0000FF 00FF00  .........
00000009: 0000FF FF0000 00FF00  .........
00000012: 00FF00 FF0000 0000FF  .........
```

If you want to strip the address off the front and the dots off the end, you can use:

```
convert start.png -depth 8 rgb: | xxd -g3 -c9 -u | sed 's/  .*//; s/^.*: //'
FF0000 0000FF 00FF00
0000FF FF0000 00FF00
00FF00 FF0000 0000FF
```

The `sed` command says... *"Anywhere you see two spaces, remove them and all that follows. Remove anything up to and including a colon followed by a space."*.

Or maybe plain dump is better:

```
convert start.png -depth 8 rgb: | xxd -g3 -c9 -u -p
FF00000000FF00FF00
0000FFFF000000FF00
00FF00FF00000000FF
```

---

Note: If using **ImageMagick** v7+, replace `convert` with `magick` in all examples above.

Answer (score 1):

opencv can read image simply.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
print(img.shape)

cy=img.shape[0]
cx=img.shape[1]
f = open('img.txt', 'w')
for row in img:
    for col in row:
        str="%02x%02x%02x"%(col[0], col[1], col[2])
        f.write(str)
f.close()
```

Comment: I don't speak Python, but you appear not to use `cy` and `cx` yet I presume you set them up for the `for` loop limits.